# splitting words defined in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code for profanity filter in an input field

```
$(function() {
$("#buttonid").on("click",function() {
    var badInput = $("input#inputid").val();
    var badwords = ["freak", "bad"];
    if($.inArray(badInput, badwords) !==-1)
    {
    alert("You cannot use the word " + badwords);
    return false;
    }
});
});
```

If the user enters the word `freak`, then it should output:

> You cannot use the word freak.

However, it output the following:

> You cannot use the word freak,bad

So, I think I need to split words defined in the variable `badwords` or to use another way. I just want the output to show the word that the user used in the input field.

Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery `inArray` function returns the position at which the item was found in the array. Use that to index into your array of profane words.

```
var word = $.inArray(badInput, badwords);
if(word !== -1)
{
    alert("You cannot use the word " + badwords[word]);
    return false;
}
```